# How do I change .equals answer (true or false) to (yes or no)?

Tags: java, string

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inpStr = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println(inpStr);
    char temp;
    char[] arr = inpStr.toCharArray();
    int len = arr.length;
    for(int i=0; i<(inpStr.length())/2; i++,len--) {
        temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[len-1];
        arr[len-1] = temp;
    }
    System.out.println("Comparing " + inpStr + " and " + String.valueOf(arr)+ " : " + inpStr.equals(String.valueOf(arr)));
}
```

The code above will output true or false, but I want it to output yes or no. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Just make use of the [StringBuilder#reverse()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/stringbuilder_reverse.htm) method within a Ternary Operator and you end up with a one liner: `System.out.println(inpStr.equalsIgnoreCase(new StringBuilder(inpStr).reverse().toString())? "Yes" : "No");`

Answer (score 1):

To convert a boolean to "yes"/"no", you'd use a condition: if it is true, then make it "yes", else make it "no":

```java
boolean value = …;
final String answer;
if (value) {
    answer = "yes";
} else {
    answer = "no";
}
```

But this is a lot to write and cannot be used as an expresison, so it is often preferred to use the ternary conditional operator instead:

```java
boolean value = …;
final String answer = value ? "yes" : "no";
```

If you don't want to repeat yourself, it is easy to wrap in a function:

```java
public static String yesNo(final boolean value) {
   if (value) {
       return "yes";
   } else {
       return "no";
   }
   // or, shorter: return value ? "yes" : "no";
}
```

then use anywhere: `boolean b = …; System.out.println(yesNo(b));`

Answer (score 0):

you could use a function to convert it or inline this code.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inpStr = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println(inpStr);
    char temp;
    char[] arr = inpStr.toCharArray();
    int len = arr.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < (inpStr.length()) / 2; i++, len--) {
      temp = arr[i];
      arr[i] = arr[len - 1];
      arr[len - 1] = temp;
    }
    System.out
        .println("Comparing " + inpStr + " and " + String.valueOf(arr) + " : " + convertFromBool(inpStr.equals(String.valueOf(arr))));
  }

  private static String convertFromBool(boolean someBool) {
    return someBool ? "Yes" : "No";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is just to use the ternary operator `?:` as follows:

```
System.out.println("Comparing " + inpStr + " and " + String.valueOf(arr)+ " : " 
       + (inpStr.equals(String.valueOf(arr)) ? "yes" : "no"));
```